# Easy UITextView and UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uitextview

Does anyone have a simple tutorial on how to easily add a TextView to a TableView? Basically re-creating a Settings-style grouped tableview type thing.

### Solution:

This is where we setup the object that we want to create, in this example, Im creating a `UISwitch`; `serverSecureAction` is where we will put what we want to happen when the switch is triggered.

Code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   //.... 

    serverSecure = [[[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(197, 8, 94, 27)] autorelease];
    serverSecure.tag = kServerTag;
    [serverSecure addTarget:self action:@selector(serverSecureAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    serverSecure.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    switch (indexPath.row)
    {
        case 0:
        {
            /*  This is where we add the subview we created above, 
                this can be used for any type of object.
             */
            [cell.textLabel setText: NSLocalizedString(@"Connect Secure", @"")];
            [cell setAccessoryView: serverSecure];
            [serverSecure setOn: TRUE];
        }
            break;
    }
    //.... 
    retun Cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is where we setup the object that we want to create, in this example, Im creating a `UISwitch`; `serverSecureAction` is where we will put what we want to happen when the switch is triggered.

```
serverSecure = [[[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(197, 8, 94, 27)] autorelease];
serverSecure.tag = kServerTag;
[serverSecure addTarget:self action:@selector(serverSecureAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
serverSecure.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

switch (indexPath.row)
{
    case 0:
    {
        /*  This is where we add the subview we created above, 
            this can be used for any type of object.
         */
        [cell.textLabel setText: NSLocalizedString(@"Connect Secure", @"")];
        [cell setAccessoryView: serverSecure];
        [serverSecure setOn: TRUE];
    }
        break;
}
```